# UnCaught Exception:Object has no method Dialog

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I know this query has been asked many times on this Portal.But Still I couldn't get the right solution.

My JS code:

```
$("#editDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $('#editDialog1').attr('href');
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Edit Customer',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 355,
                width: 400,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    //$(this).load(url);



                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
```

Html:

```
<a id="editDialog1" href="..\Home\Create">Create Customer</a>
    <div id="dialog-edit" style="display: none"/>
```

Scripts Included:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/jquery-ui.css" />
```

**Error Showing up in Console:**

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' (index):76
(anonymous function) (index):76
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.js:3256
elemData.handle.eventHandle**

But Still this error is Showing Up..I have tried including scripts marked as answers but still my issue is not resolved..Help me Guys.

Comment: `jquery-ui-1.8.11.js` is not being included correctly. Check the path and file name are correct.

Comment: With the update you are including both the minified and non-minified versions of jQueryUI. Remove one of them, probably best to remove the non-minified.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Removed tag.

Comment: Still the same error. I am not getting which dialog script I need to include in order to make it Run.

Comment: Do you see other errors on console? Maybe your js files are corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any entry for loading the main jQuery library, only jQuery UI, You need both.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
```

Also as of jQuery 1.7 $.live is deprecated, you should now use $.on

```
$("#editDialog").on("click", function (e) {...});
```

**If your using Google Chrome**

Press **CTRL + SHIFT + I** then click the **Network** Tab, Reload your page. Any file name resource titles that are RED in colour are indications the resource could not be found because it's path is incorrect or the resource is missing.

Comment: Ya.Some resource titles are in Red. Like for script: "jquery-1.10.2.min.js
/Scripts" and for "jquery-ui.css
/Content"..How can I rectify it now to make this thing work

Comment: Now only this title is showing up red "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/jquery-ui.css" />"

Comment: The file paths to you JS and CSS files are not relevant to the folder location of any HTML source output or server side folder structure, Your paths need to be relative of the host domains path to the JS/CSS files:

href="http://www.yourdomain.com/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" 
href="http://www.yourdomain.com/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" 
href="http://www.yourdomain.com/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.css"